# How do I turn on GOD mode in The Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

Is it possible to "cheat" or adapt my gameplay and to activate a GOD mode in The Witcher?

Comment: Would you accept a mod?

Comment: @tzenes Why not but I don't want to cheat on everything. My goal is to avoid dying.

Comment: I like RPG but I hate fighting. I play those kind of game for the scenario and dialogue only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a [trainer](http://www.gamershell.com/download_40932.shtml)?  These programs operate much like a "Game Genie" in that they can edit the values in memory in real-time and give you infinite health, potions, etc.  You may have to try a few before you find one that has the features you want and works with the version of the game you have.

There are also [save file editors](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Save_editor), which will edit your save file so that you have near-infinite levels of gold, potions, health, etc.

If you want a more subtle help, you might try [editing the game files](http://en.thewitcher.com/forum/index.php?/topic/16413-tw1the-witcher-mega-trainer-15/page__view__findpost__p__644295), which will give you more talents per level than you normally get, which allows you to customize your experience to an extent.

Comment: There are comments on that site that the trainer has a virus. Might not be currently accurate, but download with caution.